# Need help trying to create a one-to-many relationship using EF7, Asp.NET and SQLite

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sqlite

I am new to Entity Framework and Asp.NET, and therefore, struggling with creating database relationships within the Entity Framework.

I have two SQLite tables (Ticket and User) and have setup my entity models as follows:

```
public class Users
    {
        [ForeignKey("id")]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
    }

public class Tickets
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string c_location { get; set; }
        public string c_store_device { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime? closed_at { get; set; }
        public int priority { get; set; }
        public int? assigned_to { get; set; }
        public DateTime? due_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }

        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to use Entity Framework 7 to export an `IEnumerable<Tickets>` that includes the `User` assigned to each `Ticket`.

I have tried to create my model relationship in `MyDBContext` as a single `User` can have multiple `Tickets`, and also has a foreign key associated in my Sqlite database (`Tickets.assigned_to = User.id`):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Users - > many Tickets
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tickets)
            .WithOne(e => e.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.assigned_to);
    }
```

My result ends up with Ticket data being exported, but against every ticket I see a `null` value for `User`:

```
[{"id":10002,...,"Users":null}]
```

When I use `.Include()` within my Repository to include each `User` like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Tickets> GetAll()
        {
            return _db.Tickets.Include(t => t.Users).ToList();
        }
```

It results in the error

`HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.`

What I'm trying to retrieve is data that looks like:

```
{"Ticket";[{"id":10002,..."status":"closed"}],"Users":[{"id":"1"..."email":"johndoe@someplace.com"}]}
```

I know it probably has something to do with my relationship model, but I cannot work out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First you should really derive your Users from IdentityUser. It helps when trying to wire up the relationship, but I will give you the answer based on your current models. Your ForeignKey property should be on the child entity. By naming conventions, which is what EF uses by default, your public Users Users works better if you put a public int UsersId. Then essentially what EF will do is from your public Users Users it will go to the Users table. Then it looks for the ForeignKey which is set to Id, so now we are in the Users Table looking at the id property. Then it looks for the naming convention UsersId and if it sees it, it will set that property to the value that it saw from the Users Table Id column.

Try using this

```
 public class Users
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Tickets> Tickets { get; set; }
    }

public class Tickets
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string summary { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string c_location { get; set; }
        public string c_store_device { get; set; }
        public string category { get; set; }
        public DateTime? created_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime? closed_at { get; set; }
        public int priority { get; set; }

        public DateTime? due_at { get; set; }
        public DateTime? updated_at { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public int UsersId { get; set; }
        public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and for your Fluent API configuring

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Users - > many Tickets
        modelBuilder.Entity<Users>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Tickets)
            .WithOne();

    }
```

Now all that does is create the relationship. In order to view the specific items you want to view, use a ViewModel. So, pull the two lists you want from where you want. Then use logic to separate the list how you want them to display.

```
public class UsersViewModel() 
{

    public UsersViewModel(Users user, List<Tickets> tickets)  
    {
       this.first_name = user.first_name;
       this.last_name = user.last_name;
       this.email = user.email;
       this.Tickets = new List<Tickets>();
       foreach(var ticket in tickets)
       {
        if(ticket.UserId == user.Id)
         {
           this.Tickets.Add(ticket)
         }
       }
    }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public List<Tickets> Tickets { get; set;}

}
```

then in your controller make your list

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
   var usersList = _repository.Users.ToList();
   var ticketsList = _repository.Tickets.ToList();
   var model = new List<UsersViewModel>();
   foreach(var user in usersList)
   {
     var listItem = new UsersViewModel(user, ticketsList);
     model.Add(listItem);
   }

    return View(model);
}
```

or use a Linq query

```
    public IActionResult Index()
        {
           var usersList = _repository.Users.ToList();
           var model = new List<UsersViewModel>();
           foreach(var user in usersList)
           {
             var ticketsList = from x in _repository.Tickets where x.UserId.Equals(user.Id) select x;
             var listItem = new UsersViewModel(user, ticketsList);
             model.Add(listItem);
           }

            return View(model);
        }
```

then at the top of your view you should have

```
@model IEnumerable<UsersViewModel>
```